# After joining object is reverse

Tags: mesh

[image]After joining my eye with the rest of my character eye is deformed. How can I fix it to not break my eye structure? (see right eye of the model)

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to tell you whats wrong and there are a lot of possibilites, which would result in wild guessing. Please upload you .blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question to include it.

Comment: The eye was exactly like the left one I didn't add any transformations just a texture. I want to join it to make my character as a one object and make animation after that.

Comment: As a guess, if you used Interactive Mirror while modeling it then its scale is negative and after joining normals will be inverted which can cause noticeable changes in texture.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, any ideas how to make it look normal?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you are creating the transparent surface at the front of the eyeball. This works with a single eyeball object but the Generated output is no longer the same when the eyeball is joined to other objects.

[image]

I am not sure but I think Generated is using the bounding box of the object. Hopefully someone more experienced with using cycles Nodes will see this and can explain exactly why it gets messed up when joined and offer another solution, maybe UV unwrapping the eyeball and using the UV's output ?

In the meantime I would suggest you don't use the Texture Coordinate node, and instead make the front of the eyeball a separate material and give it a glossy transparent texture.

Comment: If you want precise texturing UV mapping is the way to go. To learn about texture coordinates watch: https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264

Comment: Yup, generated texture coords are based on object bounding box.  Joining objects can certainly lead to changes in materials using generated coords.